What is the Mixed-Radix Numeral System of Best Radix Economy?
Radix economy concerns itself with the efficiency of encoding numbers. For positional number systems that use a fixed base, base three is the most efficient choice among the integers, and $e$ is the most efficient choice in the reals. Is there a mixed-radix numbering system of integer bases that has better radix economy than the uniform base-three system?
I've been unable to find any discussion of this (to me) quite natural question. In particular, there is a rather obvious candidate scheme of selecting between base two and three for each position in an approximation of $e$. To make this precise:

For single-digit numbers, base-three is closer to base-$e$ than base-two, so use three as the base of the least significant digits.
For two-digit numbers, base-$e$ can represent $e^2 \approx 7.389$ different numbers. When using three as the base of the least significant digit, then using two as the base of the digit before that gives $2 * 3 = 6$ different two-digit numbers, whereas three would give $3*3=9$. Since $6$ is closer to $7.389$ than $9$ is, use two for the base of second-to-least significant digits.
For three-digit numbers, base-$e$ can represent $e^3 \approx 20.086$ different numbers. When using two and three as the bases of the two least significant digits, then using two as the base of the digit before that gives $2 * 2 * 3 = 12$ different two-digit numbers, whereas three would give $3 *   2 * 3 = 18$. Since $18$ is closer to $20.086$ than $12$ is, use three for the base of third-to-least significant digits.
And so on, greedily choosing the better approximation of base-$e$ for each successively more significant digit. The result is a series of bases alternating between two and three, with the occasional successive threes.

As an example, $16$ (decimal) would be written as $211$ in this system ($2*(2*3) + 1 * (3) + 1$).
Things that I'm curious about:

Any prior art on optimality questions around mixed-integral-base number systems.
Any discussion of this specific greedy-$e$-approximation system (I cannot possibly be the first person to consider this one).
Anything that could point toward efficiently determining the radix of the $k$-th least-significant digit in the greedy-$e$-approximation system in fewer than $\mathcal{O}(k)$ computation steps.

(I'm trained as a computer scientist, not as a mathematician. So while I can handle some discrete math, the real numbers "scare" me, which limits how far I can get with this on my own.)

Since $\exp(3)$ is close to $20$, we can "score" close to the optimum using a cyclic pattern of base $2$ with base $5$.
Since the mlnatural logarithm of $2$ is closer to $1$ than tge natural logarithm of $5$, we use base $2$ for the units digit. But then $\ln(10)$ is closer to $2$ than $\ln(4)$, so we use base $5$ for the twos digit. Then base $2$ for the tens digit to get a product of $20$ and repeat this cycle.
With this system we can do arithmetic using only finite addition and multiplication tables, in effect adapting the tables for ordinary base $20$.

Could you clarify "close to the optimum" for me, please? Is the optimum here the radix economy achieved by $e$, or by base-three?
Technically, the standard proof that $e$ is the single radix of optimal radix economy does not even imply that $e$-everywhere is also optimal when allowing for mixed-radix systems.
I do like the nice computational properties of your system, especially if it is more economic than base-three.
